# Setting subviews layout anchors to UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, nslayoutanchor

When i want to set top anchors of my subviews in a `UIScrollView`, i have to give them a constant height, otherwise scrollView won't scroll. But As they grow in number, it feels like a mess.

For example, if i set my 2nd subviews' `topAnchor` to first one's `bottomAnchor`, it won't scroll. I have to set them to scrollView's anchor.
Is there a better way to achieve this without giving a constant and calculating the distance myself?

Here is my scrollView:

```
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 500)
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

    belowContainer.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: belowContainer.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: belowContainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: belowContainer.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: belowContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

And i use the following variables to get the vertical spacing right, between the subViews

```
    var counter : CGFloat = 0; // height space counter between uiItems below!
    let multiplierHeight : CGFloat = 32 // we multiply our counter by this value to get the right spacing!
```

And finally i got my subviews anchoring in a for-loop like this:

```
    for lbl in labelsArray {
        lbl.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 20)

        lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: counter * multiplierHeight).isActive = true          
        lbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
        counter += 1
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn’t appear to be the right solution to your problem. Rather, you should cascade the labels such that one label’s bottom constraint is linked to the next label’s top constraint. This way, you won't have to do the top constraint constant multiplication.

You might, however, want to consider using a stack view to achieve your goal. Pin the stack view to the scroll view’s content view using constraints, and then use your `for` loop to add the labels to the stack view:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(lbl)
```

The stack view has the advantage that you won't need a single layout constraint. Rather, the stack view itself is responsible for positioning its subviews.

Comment: i'll give stackView a try, but like i said, when i set one of the subviews topAnchor to another ones, let's say, bottomAnchor, UIScrollView will not allow me to scroll, the subview kind of gets stuck and does not move, and that is the problem

Comment: The problem could be that you are nailing the scrollView’s height to a fixed 500 px instead of allowing it to grow according to contents. You might rather leave the `contentSize` untouched, set the content view˚s with (i. e. the stack view width) to the width of the view port and let auto layout determine the height.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my mistake was that i was not using a `UIStackView`, instead i was using a basic UIView instance or no container in the scrollView. Using StackView worked like a charm. But i have to set `contentSize`, otherwise it does not scroll again.